# JS/CSS Issue : my element didn't fully overlapped, when using z-index it stopped the javascript

Tags: javascript, z-index

i created a web-based forum, i want to put the banner in sidebar and header menu. I want that sidebar banner and header didn't move down when i scroll down the web. I try using javascript, it works but some elements overlapping the other.

THE BAD NEWS IS: I EVEN CAN PUT THE CODE IN HERE

this is my site http://forum.wirada.net/

if i add z-index in javascript code, it didn't want to stay when i scroll down
Please...please...
anyone can help me?
sorry for my bad english and question...

Comment: Add `position: fixed` in your stylesheet for header and sidebar menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the z-index of div id="scrolling-content" then the text won't overlap.

```
<div id="scrolling-content" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 100;">
```

I noticed you have used table structure quite heavily (3 nested tables) for creating the web layout. Nowadays layout structure is done using divs. Div layouts are much easier to handle.

Comment: thx hade, it's work.
btw, if i want to attrib the td's table with the div like above, can it work?
btw, have you any suggestion to change table to div?
thx..

Comment: I would suggest moving all style definitions into separate css file. It helps a lot. I have purchased this WordPress template. I think it has great structure (http://demo.brankic.net/bigbangwp/). Just google "DIV based web layout" and you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: I'm using Firefox plugin called Firebug to examine html & css content.